# Test assert_broadcast_on without specifying the message content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-6

I am writing tests for a Rails 6 app.

I have an action, `post "/action"`, that implies messages broadcasted to a channel, `user_channel1`.

I tried to use [assert_broadcast_on](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-assert_broadcasts) in my integration tests.

```rb
assert_broadcast_on("user_channel1") do
      post "/action"
end
# Error: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) ...
```

I would like to know if it's possible to test that messages are broadcasted without giving the exact messages content.
Thanks!

Note: messages can be json formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check count of broadcasts in channel

```
assert_broadcasts 'user_channel1', 1
```